# How to compare data from 2 databases with different primary and foreign keys?

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm, sqlite, data-comparison

I need to compare 2 databases on their datas. But I have to compare only the data, **not the keys**, which may be different (but the relations between objets must be the same).

Actually it is a need to verify the proper functioning of a data conversion tool.

### Simple example:

I use an entity-framework on C# .Net and Sqlite, here's the database schema:

```
public partial class Document
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public Int64 idDocument { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Diagram
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public Int64 idDiagram { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public partial class Document_contains_diagram
{
    public Int64 idDocument { get; set; }
    public Int64 idDiagram { get; set; }
}
```

The database :

Tables in order : Document - Diagram - Document_contains_diagram

| idDocument | name |  | idDiagram | title |  | idDocument | idDiagram |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "myFirstDocument" |  | 1 | "evolution" |  | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | "mySecondDocument" |  | 2 | "futur" |  | 2 | 2 |

Should be considered as same as:

| idDocument | name |  | idDiagram | title |  | idDocument | idDiagram |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | "myFirstDocument" |  | 8 | "evolution" |  | 3 | 8 |
| 4 | "mySecondDocument" |  | 6 | "futur" |  | 4 | 6 |

It's an example, the true database I want to compare contains more than 50 tables and often more than 10000 entries (RAM limit is a contraint too).
So I'm looking for an **generic** algorythm, or a tool to compare theses 2 databases that might help me in my search. All tools I've seen only check for strict equality of the tables. Maybe converting the database into a graph would works ?

Comment: Would it be possible in your scenario to use a Hash-Checksum of each row, but without the IDs?

Comment: In this case, if I make a hash/checksum it will lose relations between objects. A diagram could be assigned to the other document and it would be the same checksum.

Comment: Are the names (non-id columns) unique within their tables? So that e.g. "name" or "title" can serve as a kind of fallback "primary key"? Or do you e.g. have multiple diagrams titled "futur"?

Comment: No non-id columns are not unique.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an automated tool to do this, but I would recommend building a one-off solution for finding a canonical arrangement of the data.  Then comparing canonical versions.

What I mean is this.  You'd export all of the data, and import it into SQLite.  Then for each table you define a canonical order.  You then migrate IDs into canonical ones, then migrate all of the IDs.  Repeat.

Much of the structure can be automatically generated.  But I'd recommend automatically generating a configuration that you then fix for the weird edge cases that always exist.

In your case the configuration might look something like this:

```
[
    # table, column, orderBy, foreign references
    # each order by is [column list]
    # each foreign reference is [table, column]
    ["Document", "idDocument", ["name"], [["Document_contains_diagram", "idDocument"]]],
    ["Diagram.idDiagram", ["title"], [["Document_contains_diagram", "idDiagram"]]],
    ...
]
```

What your tool would do with it is:

```
For each entry:
    Create a conversion table with a query like:

        create table tmp_convert as (
            select {table}.{id_column} as old_id,
                row_number() over (order by {columns here}) as new_id
            from {table}
        );

    Add an index to tmp_convert.old_id

    Update {table}.{id_column} using tmp_convert

    for each foreign reference:
        Update foreign reference using tmp_convert

    drop tmp_convert
```

So in your example it would take the first database, and after a bunch of work find that it was in canonical order.  It would take the second database, and for `idDocument` would replace 3 with 1 everywhere, and 4 with 2.  For `idDiagram` it would replace 8 with 1 and 6 with 2.  Once it did this, the two databases are now identical, so they would match.